# Rails reviews not showing up on album show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Albums have many reviews and users through reviews, Reviews belong to album and belong to user, and Users have many reviews and have many albums through reviews.

On my albums show page, Reviews do not display. But Reviews display on the reviews index page. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. I'm not getting any errors.

Here is my Albums controller:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_album, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

    def index
        @albums = Album.all
        @current_user
    end

    def show
        @review = @album.reviews.build
    end

    def new
        @album = Album.new
    end

    def create
        @album = Album.new(album_params)
        if @album.save
            redirect_to album_path(@album)
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @album.update(album_params)
            redirect_to album_path(@album), notice: "Your album has been updated."
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

    def set_album
        @album = Album.find(params[:id])
    end

    def album_params
        params.require(:album).permit(:artist, :title, :avatar)
    end
end
```

Reviews Controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @reviews = Review.all
    end

    def show
        @review = Review.find(params[:id])
        #@reviews = Review.where("album_id = ?", params[:album_id])
    end

    def new
        @review = Review.new
    end

    def create
        @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
        if @review.save
            redirect_to reviews_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def update

    end

    private

    def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:title, :date, :content, :user_id, :album_id, album_attributes:[:artist, :title])
    end

end
```

Here is my albums show page:

```
<% if @album.avatar.attached? %>
    <image src="<%=(url_for(@album.avatar))%>%" style="width:350px;height:350px;">
<% end %>
<br>
<%= @album.artist %> -
<%= @album.title %>
<br>
<%= link_to "Edit Album", edit_album_path %>
<br><br><br>

<%= render '/reviews/form' if logged_in? %>
    <h3>Album Reviews</h3>
<% @album.reviews.each do |review| %>
        <%= review.title %>
        <%= review.content %>
<% end %>

<br><br><br>
<%= link_to "All Albums", albums_path %><br>
<%= link_to "Upload a New Album", new_album_path %>
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/signup' => 'users#new', as: 'signup'
  post '/signup' => 'users#create'
  get '/signin' => 'sessions#new'
  post '/signin' => 'sessions#create'
  get '/signout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :albums do
    resources :reviews, except: [:index]
  end
  resources :users
  resources :reviews, only: [:index]

  root to: "albums#index"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here are my Models:

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :users, through: :reviews
    has_one_attached :avatar
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :album, optional: true
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :album
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :albums, through: :reviews
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
end
```

Review form:

```
<%= form_for :review, method: "POST",:url => { :action => :create } do |f| %> 
<!-- <%= f.collection_select :album_id, Album.order(:artist),:id,:artist %> -->
<br>
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title%>
            <br><br>
      <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= f.datetime_field :date%>
            <br><br>
      <%= f.label :content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
            <br><br>
      <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The most important part is your models and they missing please add them as well, also add your migration files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the iteration, because you use the instance variable coming from the controller instead of the block variable, it should be:

```
<% @album.reviews.each do |review| %>
  <%= review.title %>
  <%= review.content %>
<% end %>
```

`@review` is a new instance of a review (empty) which you created for the form I guess.

So instead of showing each review's title and content you showed the one from the empty review saved in `@review` in each iteration.

Comment: Are you sure you have reviews for the album you're testing it on?  Sorry to ask, but sometimes it's the easiest things

Comment: I think so??? My reviews might not be adding to each specific album, but how could I check that? I'll post more of my code

Comment: You can open the rails console with `rails c` in your terminal and create reviews for a specific album, this way you will make sure you have nice data. Alternatively you can write a small script in the seed file and run it with `rails db:seed`.

Comment: OK I actually just noticed Reviews.all in the console reveals that album_id is nil on everything. So how do I attach reviews to albums?

Comment: It might be good to create another question for that, because this is a bit of a different topic and we need to see other files.
So open another question and I will check on your profile. Probably it's in the `reviews_controller` in `create` where you need to assign the new review to an album. With the nested params you should receive the album id through the params, than you can find the album (`@album = Album.find(params[:album_id]`) and then `@review.album = @album`.
But now create a test review in the console first and check if this problem is solved :)

Comment: Both things? If not I am happy to answer a new question.
Also, I would be very glad if you could acdept the answer :)

Comment: Yes, finding the album in reviews#create and then review.album = album was all I needed to do. onto new errors and issues but at least this one is resolved :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211503/discussion-between-clara-and-mel).